# Does SSH is a P2P connection?

Tags: ssh

In my network, P2P connection forbidden for Torrent etc...

My **SSH** connection request stays unresponsive so can be prevented by P2P filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packet filtering is often done by looking at the TCP or UDP port numbers, and blocking ones that are deemed harmful or unnecessary. Some places might block everything that isn't an outgoing HTTP(S) connection... It could also be done by looking inside the contents of the packets, either via forcing the use of an application-level proxy server, or by just trying to recognize the protocol used from the first few packets of a connection.

No, SSH isn't a peer-to-peer protocol, it just uses a single TCP connection. But either method above could block SSH as well (and probably better) than blocking BitTorrent; it's not about peer-to-peer vs. otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody knows except those who set up the firewall rules for "your network".

Both ssh and torrent connections can be filtered, but the actual rules don't mention "P2P", nor do they care how you define "P2P.

And if the ssh request just hangs, then yes, very likely it's filtered *somewhere*.